# difficulty in proving ''If f is continuous then $\left\|{f}\right\|=0$ implies $f(x)\equiv 0$

Tags: integration, orthonormal

I have read in a textbook that '' if a function f(x) is continuous then $$\left\|{f}\right\|=\sqrt{\left({f(x),f(x)}\right)}=\sqrt{\int\limits_{a}^{b}{r(x)f(x)^{2}dx}}=0$$ implies that $$f(x)\equiv 0$$
(The weight function r is positive)
How is it possible that a non-zero discontinuous function has zero norm?

Comment: If you change a function at a single point (or a countable number of points), you won't change its integral, hence you won't change its norm, and so a function with norm zero only has to be zero "almost everywhere" (a technical term).  But a continuous function that is zero almost everywhere is actually zero everywhere.

Comment: What is $r$ in your quote? + replace "continues" by "continuous" + Your title is not coherent with your question.

Comment: @AnneBauval    r is the weight function that is norm of f is zero with respect to the weight function r(x)

Comment: I knew, but better add it into your post than as a comment, and with the appropriate hypothesis on $r.$